# How to tail a file using a NIO selector, in other words, as lines are added to the file a channel is selected so you can read the lines?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, io, nio, filechannel

Because you cannot [redirect GC logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852774/has-anyone-played-with-nio-pipes-to-filter-intercept-system-out) I am left with the option to redirect it to a file with -Xloggc and then get the contents of this file inside my selector through a file channel of some kind. Basically as lines are being added to my file, the selector is being triggered to read them. That way I can get the GC logs programmatically. Is it possible to do that using NIO?

Answer (score 0):

No. FileChannel does not extend SelectableChannel so you can't select with it, and even in C where you can, select() doesn't deliver readable events when the file is extended (it delivers them every time you select, as the file is always readable).

Answer (score 0):

Given GC logs are buffered, I wouldn't worry about a bit of latency.  You can just poll the file length periodically and read the data added each time. You can do this in IO, NIO or NIO2.